# Android Studio Native Development: Javah input parameters

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, javah

I've been trying to get Native Development off the ground today in Android Studio. I think I have everything set up correctly, except for javah. When trying to run it I get thrown the error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name: Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program"
```

I set javah up as an external tool in the settings menu; here's what the dialog box looks like:

[image: External Tool DialogBox]

I'm almost certain that the error is within the "parameters" field.

Ideas? Have I input the commands incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The problem is the white space in the JDK path : C:**Program Files**\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\javah.exe. In my case, I simply copy my JDK to a new folder whose path contains no white space and it works now!